# splitting textarea elements into array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have been trying to split my inputs in the text area. I was able to split every row. But I want to separate the elements in these rows also and put it in an array. I could not arrive at it.

Only after splitting the rows, I can make calculation for the finding GPA and everything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>GPA Calculator</h1><br>
        <textarea id="grad" rows="15" cols="25">

        </textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">Compute GPA</button><br>

        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="Dmo"></p>


        <script>
            function myfunction() {
                var ch = 0,
                    gp = 0,
                    gpa = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var pp = [];
                var x = document.getElementById("grad").value.split('\n');
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                /*var pro=x.split('\t')[0];
           pre = parseInt(pre,10); */
                /* var pro= [];
                 var pre=[];
                 var mid=[];
                var pro= x.split(" ")[0];
                 var mid=x.split(" ")[1];
                 var pre=x.split(" ")[2];
                 document.write(pro);
                   document.write(pre);
                }
        </script>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my output screen. I want to split the first index also bu I'm not able to.
[image]

Comment: Where is your input data? Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ask your question in better way by putting technical difficulty you are having with JavaScript. For example: How to parse text input in a HTML TextArea tag, separated with rows and tabs with new line and column respectively?